# How to transfer more than 65536 rows from Access to excel 2007

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, excel-2007, export-to-excel

How to transfer more than 65536 rows from Access to excel 2007.

There is no limitaion on the part of Excel 2007 as the new version supports much more than 65536 rows in Excel. Limitation is coming on the part of Clipboard. It is not allowing to export or to Copy more than 65536 rows from Access.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Data -> Import?

What's wrong with that? I've used it many times for importing thousands of records.

Just define the data source and import it.

Answer (score -2):

Almost certainly this is a timeout or a memory issue. The only PHPExcel limit for worksheets size is 65,536 rows and 256 (IV) columns (when using the Excel5 Writer); or 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 (XFD) columns (when using the Excel2007 Writer).

If you are using PHPExcel Library then You can change this line 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
as
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

Then it allows to write records more than 65536 rows.
It works for me.

Comment: The question hasn't mentioned PHP or PHPExcel